# Syntax Error al importar base de datos en PhpMyAdmin

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, phpmyadmin

Quiero importar una base de datos que me descargué de google, pero al querer importarla desde phpMyAdmin, me salta un error de sintaxis en el archivo, y la verdad es que no veo el fallo, tampoco he usado SQL, entonces no tengo ni idea de como funciona su sintaxis...
El error me dice que está en la línea 4 del siguiente código:

```
CREATE TABLE phurl_settings (
  last_number bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  KEY last_number (last_number)
) TYPE=MyISAM;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La palabra clave `TYPE` fue declarada obsoleta desde la versión 5.5 de MySQL y removida definitivamente a partir de la versión 6.0. Esa palabra fue cambiada por `ENGINE`, por tanto debes escribir la consulta de este modo:

```
CREATE TABLE phurl_settings (
  last_number bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  KEY last_number (last_number)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

#### Enlaces

- [Documentación actual al respecto](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/storage-engine-setting.html)
- [Exposición del caso en el reporte de bugs](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=47974)